# Generalisations which a bi-gram probabilistic model might infer from a dataset

Tags: corpora, grammar, machine-translation, statistical-mt

I have the following exam question for a machine translation course:

[image: examquestion]

From my understanding, I assume the answer is looking for incorrect English grammar which get discovered by bi-grams.

So the answer would contain:

```
I are
I right
I wrong
```

I am unsure of how to fully answer the question i.e what the generalisations are. Can anybody shed some light on this?